# Publishing notifications after app is killed

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I've been trying to make notifications for my calendar-day planner app for about a week. The notifications work fine as long as the app is in the recent-tasks, but when removed it simply doesn't work.

Initially I tried using simply AlarmManager that calls for a BroadcastReciever but I understood it doesn't offer this functionality so I decided to learn and use Service.

At first I tried IntentService, now I'm trying Service. I don't get any log errors so I'm guessing there's a fundamental issue with my understanding of this system so I'll appreciate if you could enlighten me.

Here's my class handling notifications as a whole:

```
package com.example.android.calendar.Helpers;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.example.android.calendar.Model.Event;
import com.example.android.calendar.R;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;

public class NotificationService extends Service {

    private static Context mContext;
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "notificationChannelId";
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "eventsNotificationChannel";

    public static final String EX_ID = "extraId";
    public static final String ACTION_START_SERVICE = "startService";
    public static final String ACTION_NOTIFY_ON_TIME = "notifyOnTime";

    private static HashMap<UUID, Notification> notifications = new HashMap<>();
    public static int mCounter = 0;

    public NotificationService(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        createNotificationChannel(this.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(intent.getAction() == ACTION_NOTIFY_ON_TIME){
                    UUID id = (UUID) intent.getSerializableExtra(EX_ID);
                    Notification notification = notifications.get(id);
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(mCounter++, notification);
                }
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        return IntentService.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void createNotificationChannel(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100});
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        mNM.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    public void createNotification(int minutesBefore, Event event){
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID).
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground).setContentTitle(event.getLabel()).
                setContentText(event.getComment()).setAutoCancel(true);

        // If an event is edited, remove existing notification
        if(notifications.get(event.getId()) != null)
            notifications.remove(event.getId());

        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        notifications.put(event.getId(), mBuilder.build());
        mCalendar.setTime(event.getTime());
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationService.class);
        intent.putExtra(EX_ID, event.getId());
        intent.setAction(ACTION_NOTIFY_ON_TIME);
        PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, (int)System.currentTimeMillis(),
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        long triggerInMills = mCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + triggerInMills, notificationIntent);
    }

    public void cancelNotification(Event event, PendingIntent notificationIntent){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(notificationIntent);
        notifications.remove(event.getId());
    }
}
```

Pretty sure it's irrelevant, but here's where I create and start the service:

```
notificationService = new NotificationService();
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationService.class);
startServiceIntent.setAction(NotificationService.ACTION_START_SERVICE);
getActivity().startService(startServiceIntent);
```

Comment: look into one signal.

Comment: What do you mean by signal?

Comment: 'One Signal' onesignal.com

Answer (score 1):

In Android Oreo, [background execution limits have changed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background), so if you are testing on >= Api 26 that's why you are likely experiencing this behavior. I would check this first.

In addition to the background execution limits, you seem to be starting a service to send off a `Notification` using `AlarmManager`.

Why not just schedule the `AlarmManager` to start this service and post the `Notification` using the `NotificationManager` via [NotificationManager#notify (int id, Notification notification)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) from the service?

Also, since this is a started service, you may or may not have a call to stopService in the same Fragment or Activity that started the service.

[As per the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#CreatingAService), you should do this for started services or have a call to `stopSelf()` in the service when the service is **done** doing its work.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Why would it be better to have AlarmManager start the service, rather then starting the service when the fragment is created? Is it because starting it before having a notificaiton is redundant or there's a deeper issue? (just geniually intrested, I'm going to change it anyway because it redundant).
About execution limits, in what way is it represented in the device settings? Because in the notifications settings everything is On for all apps.

Comment: Well, it appears all the service is doing is creating the notification and scheduling it with the AlarmManager. That is not really the practical use case for a service. You can just schedule alarms from the fragment directly.